# Вопрос по питону:

Tags: python

Если список `Second_row` имеет 6 символов то код работает , а если 5 так как сейчас, то выбивает ошибку что `е6` не может присвоиться так как не находится. Как сделать, чтобы блок пропускался вместо того, чтобы выдавал ошибку. Но если число под индексом 6 присутствовало, то работал.

```
z1=''
z2=''
z3=''
z4=''
z5=''
z6=''
z7=''
z8=''
z9=''

Second_row=('123457')


if len(Second_row)>5:
    e6 = Second_row[6]
    for item in e6:
        if e6=='1':
            z1=z1+e6
        elif e6=='2':
            z2=z2+e6
        elif e6=='3':
            z3=z3+e6
        elif e6=='4':
            z4=z4+e6
        elif e6=='5':
            z5=z5+e6
        elif e6=='6':
            z6=z6+e6
        elif e6=='7':
            z7=z7+e6
        elif e6=='8':
            z8=z8+e6
        elif e6=='9':
            z9=z9+e6
```

Comment: Мне интересно, в чем полезность данной конструкции?

Comment: Опишите более широко вашу проблему. И укажите какая выдается ошибка.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

В языке программирования Python, как и в подавляющем числе языков программирования, нумерация элементов массива начинается с нуля. Следовательно, выражение `Second_row[6]` обращается к **седьмому** элементу массива, которого в данном случае просто не существует. Тому доказательство - сообщение интерпретатора об ошибке:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 15, in <module>
    e6 = Second_row[6]
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Чтобы исправить ошибку, нужно записать это выражение так: `Second_row[5]`.

P.S. А в качестве задачки на сообразительность, подумайте, зачем там цикл и что будет, если его убрать.